# Saving User State in SQL Database?

Tags: sql, database-design

Say I have 3 tables: `films`, `parts` & `scenes`. Scenes appear in Parts which appear in Films, in a particular order:

```
films
 - id
 - title
```

```
parts
 - id
 - film_id        // references the films table
 - position       // position in film: Part 1 / 2 / 3, ...
```

```
scenes
 - id
 - part_id        // references the parts table
 - position       // position in part: Scene 1, Scene 2 (of a particular part) ...
```

Now for simplicity's sake let's say a user looks at a view that shows her all scenes. She can click on a scene and select it or unselect it.

**Problem:** I am wondering how I would store this state in SQL? I know how to store the films, parts, scenes, which are the same for every user. But what has or has not been clicked on is part of the users personal state. I would like to save this, but it will differ for each user.

Would I create a separate table for this in my database? How would I then retrieve this very personalised data for each user? And: Won't this make my SQL incredibly slow, esp. if there is a lot more to store at some point than just clicked / not clicked?

**My Attempt:** Right now, my solution would be to have a table like this:

```
user-article-state
 - user_id
 - scene_id
 - isClicked
```

...but would this work? does it even make sense to create a separate table for something like this? It seems bloated to me - I feel like maybe I am missing something, and this is not how SQL should be used? Esp. since now all the (user states of) scenes of all the parts of all the films will be in one massive table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of `Users` and a table of `Scenes` and you want to store which Scenes have been selected by which Users, then what you have is an entity representing a many-to-many relationship between those two tables.  You might call it something like `UserScenes` or `UserSceneSelections`.

Effectively all it stores is foreign keys back to those tables:

```
UserID (FK to Users table)
SceneID (FK to Scenes table)
```

Depending on your data access framework or personal preference, you might also give each record an ID:

```
ID (PK)
UserID (FK to Users table)
SceneID (FK to Scenes table)
```

Otherwise the combination of `UserID` and `SceneID` makes for a natural primary key as well, since it wouldn't make sense for the same User to select the same Scene multiple times.

If more data about these selections needs to be added, such as a timestamp of when it was selected, that can be added here as well.  But effectively you're just maintaining a many-to-many table linking the primary entities, Users and Scenes.